# Java Audio Byte Buffer takes varying times to fill

Tags: java, audio, byte, buffer, bytebuffer

I am opening a targetdataline to accept audio input for a given format. 
I start and open the line,  and I have a buffer which fills with bytes.  This runs on a constant loop until an external parameter is changed.

Now for a fixed sample rate and buffer size, I would expect this to always take the same amount of time to fill,  ie if my buffer size was 48000 for an 8 bit stream, and my sample rate was 48kHz,  I would expect my buffer to always take 1 second to fill.  However I am finding this varying greatly.

The following is the code I have used:

```
 DataLine.Info info1 = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format1);

     try (TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) m1.getLine(info1)) {
         line.open(format1);
            line.start();

            while (!pauseInput){
            long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();


            int numBytesRead1 = line.read(buffer1, 0, buffer1.length);

            //chan1double = deinterleaveAudio(buffer1, chan1selectedchannel, chan1totalchannels);
            long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(threadName + " Capture time = " + (time2-time1));
            }
         line.stop(); 

     }
```

The commented line is a process I want to run each time the buffer is full. I realise I cannot place this here as it will interrupt the stream, so I need to find a different way to call this, hence I have commented out.

For testing purposes I have a buffer size of 4096. My audio format is 48kHz 16-bit,  so I would expect my byte buffer to be filled in 42.6ms. ((1/48000) * 2048). (this is multiplied by half the buffer size as each sample is two bytes). However using the currentTimeMillies to measure each pass it is coming back with 123ms and 250ms and varying between those times.

Is there something I am missing out here that I have not done?

EDIT:  I have copied just the code into a brand new application that doesn't even have a GUI or anything attached to it.  Purely to output to the console and see what is happening, making sure there are no background threads to interfere, and sure enough the same happens. 95% of the time the buffer with predicted fill time of 250ms fills within 255-259ms.  However occasionally this will drop to 127ms (which is physically impossible unless there is some weird buffer thing going on.  Is this a bug in java somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a good idea to adjust timing such a way. It depends on many things e.g., bufferSize, mixer, etc. Moreover, your application is sharing the line's buffer with the mixer. If you have a real-time processing, store your data in a *circular buffer* with a length that is good enough to hold the amount of data that you need. In another thread, read the desired amount of data from the *circular buffer*, and do your processing at a constant time interval. Thus, sometimes, you may overlap or miss some bytes between two consecutive processings, but you always have the expected amount of bytes.

When you open the line, you can specify the line's buffer size by using [`open(format, bufferSize)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/TargetDataLine.html#open(javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat,%20int)) or you can check actual buffer size by 
calling [`DataLine.getBufferSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#getBufferSize()). Then you need to specify the size of your short buffer that you are providing when you retrieve data through [`TargetDataLine.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/TargetDataLine.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)). Your short buffer size has to be smaller than the line's buffer size. I would consider short buffer size as 1/4th, 1/8th, 1/16th or so of the line's buffer size. Another idea is checking the available bytes [`DataLine.available()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#available()) before calling `read()`. Note that `read()` is a blocking call (but it doesn't block line's buffer), i.e., it will be stuck until the requested amount of bytes have been read.

For low latency direct communication between your application and audio interface, you may consider [ASIO](http://[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Stream_Input/Output]).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  But I am confused.  I am not looking at adjusting timing. I am more confused about why the time taken to fill the buffer varies.  It should take the same amount of milliseconds to fill the same buffer size, if the time varies it leads to jitter issues or variations in pitch.  

I would very much like to implement the circular buffer as suggested. But if the audio stream is susceptible to timing variations using java sound maybe I am better using a different interface to the hardware. I have read about several C implementations that are wrapped using JNI.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at the same issue, I have been given an answer which half explains what is happening.

The thread scheduler decides when the code can run, and this can cause this to vary by 10-20ms.  In the earlier days this was as much as 70ms. 
This does not mean the stream is missing samples, but just that this buffer will not provide a continuous stream.  So any application look at processing this data in realtime and passing it to be written to an audio output stream needs to be aware of this extra potential latency.

I am still looking at the reason for the short buffer fill time, every four or five passes.  I was told it could be to do with the targetDataLine buffer size being different to my buffer size and just the remainder of that buffer being written on that pass, however I have changed this to be exactly the same and still no luck.